# Java: NumberFormatException in converting string to integer

Tags: java

I want to retrieve value from textbox and convert it to integer. I wrote the following code but it throws a `NumberFormatException`.

```
String nop = no_of_people.getText().toString();
System.out.println(nop);
int nop1 = Integer.parseInt(nop);
System.out.println(nop1);
```

The first call to `System.out.println` prints me the number but converting to integer gives an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does it print ? Can you tell us the *exact* string

Comment: Always use try/catch when trying to parse a string coming from a textbox. And do basic cleaning, like using the trim() function.

Comment: Make sure the trim the string before you convert it to Integer.

Comment: the input given in textbox was 4. First system.out prints 4.

Comment: Try wih `trim()` there could be spaces around

Comment: The string `"4"` will definitely not cause `parseInt` to throw an exception. Try it out for yourself.

Comment: we tried using trim().. but not working :(

Comment: Then use try{//your code of parsing}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ex.printstacktrace();} and tell us the exception stacktrace

Comment: How did you use trim(), can you please mention the code?

Comment: If you try and highlight the text you are printing you will most likely notice one or more white space behind and/or after the value you are printig.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the parsing will fail if there are any white spaces in your string. You could either trim the string first by using the `.trim` method or else, do a replace all using the `.replaceAll("\\s+", "")`.

If you want to avoid such issues, I would recommend you use a [Formatted Text Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or a [Spinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

The latter options will guarantee that you have numeric values and should avoid you the need of using try catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your TextBox may contain number with a white space. Try following edited code. You need to trim the TextBox Value before converting it to Integer. Also make sure that value is not exceeding to integer range.

```
String nop=(no_of_people.getText().toString().trim());
System.out.println(nop);
int nop1 = Integer.parseInt(nop);
System.out.println(nop1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int nop1 = Integer.parseInt(no_of_people.getText().toString().trim());
System.out.println(nop1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing all `non-digit characters` from String first converting to `int`:

```
replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

You can use this code:

```
String nop=(no_of_people.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
System.out.printf("nop=[%s]%n", nop);
int nop1 = Integer.parseInt(nop);
System.out.printf("nop1=[%d]%n", nop1);
```

Comment: I suggest not to do that. Entering "12.34" or "12,34" (depending on locale to be used for floating point) and getting that converted to the integer 1234 _without warning or error_ may be much worse (depending on the application) than a crash.

Comment: @Bananeweizen: OP is trying to convert a String to int not float or double.

Comment: I know that. But what matters is,if the _user_ of his application knows that or if that user is protected from making mistakes by just entering a floating point value.